# Rename key field in all documents: duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have  4000 of documents  I need to change the one key of whole documents
what I have tried is

```
db.qa_opportunities.updateMany({},{$rename :{"tx_date":"review_date"}})
```

but it is created two one is tx_date and another is review_date some of the values are moved to tx_date and some are review_date 
and the error is :

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: fielding.qa_opportunities.$tx_date_1_emp_no_1_chat_id_1 dup key: { : null, : \"P111993\", : 4343675 }"
    }
})
```

I need all values to represent only review date. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You currently have an index which includes the tx_date field (among others), and because the index is configured to be *unique*, when you remove the tx_date field you end up with duplicate index keys.

I would try the following:

1. Analyse all your indexes, and make a note of any which reference the tx_date field
2. *Remove* those indexes
3. Rename the key from tx_date to review_date
4. *Recreate* each index, to reference the new key name review_date in place of the old key name tx_date.